# tengo problemas al usar rutas en react

Tags: reactjs

bueno al momento de ejecutar mi aplicación va todo normal , el problema inicia cuando intento seleccionar un elemento del DOM con document.querySelector , al seleccionar lo mando ese elemento a consola y me dice NULL

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]